# Bivariate Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, joint-distribution, bivariate

How can I prove $F$ is a bivariate distribution function where

$F(x_1,x_2)=F_1(x_1)F_2(x_2)[1-t(1-F_1(x_1))(1-F_2(x_2))]$

$F_1$ and $F_2$ are univariate distribution functions. And $-1\leq t\leq1$

$F(\infty,\infty)=1$, $F(x_1,-\infty)=F(-\infty,x_2)=0$ and $F$ is right continuous can be proven easily. How can I prove that 
$F(x+h,y+k)-F(x+h,y)-F(x,y+k)+F(x,y)>0$ ?

Comment: You cannot, because it's not true: but you can prove the result with "$\gt$" replaced by "$\ge$".  You only need demonstrate that $F(x+h,y)-F(x,y)\ge 0$ for all $x,y,$ and $h\ge 0$, because of the symmetry of the expression. A little algebra will show this follows directly from the assumption that $|t|\le 1$, $F_1$ is non-decreasing, and $0\le F_1(x)\le 1$ for all $x$.